# modal popup extender as progress bar

Tags: parent, modalpopupextender, blur

I have a modal popup extender in which i have a progress bar.
When i click a button ...this popup should be displayed to the user.

I have done this though button.attributes.add().[ this is without postback]

But ...popup extender can blur the base page only after the postback.

Issue is currently i am able to see the progress bar...but base page is not blurred.

:(

Any help

Answer (score 0):

Here 2 link that will help you

[How to make ModalUpdate Progress Bar on page?](http://vincexu.blogspot.com/2008/10/how-to-make-modalupdate-progress-bar-on.html)

[ModalPopup as an AJAX Progress Indicator](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/07/modalpopup_as_an_ajax_progress.html)